# What is the difference between MTB and road bike cassette if the parameters are the same?

Tags: mountain-bike, road-bike, cassette

My road bike has a 10 speed Shimano CS-HG500 cassette (11-32), and I would like to buy a new one for the indoor trainer. Unfortunately I don't find any 10 speed road cassette on stock(eu), but I found a 10 speed SLX CS-HG81 (11-32). Can I just put this on my roadbike, or what is the difference basically between the two cassettes (MTB and road) when the parameters are the same?

Thanks,
Mate

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The colour/finish/surface treatment and construction of the largest sprockets' carrier is different. However, from a technical perspective, they are interchangeable. Even the individual ratios between the 11 and 32 cog are the same:

- [Shimano CS-HG500-10](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/grx-10-speed/CS-HG500-10.html): `11-12-14-16-18-20-22-25-28-32T`
- [Shimano CS-HG81-10](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/slx-m7000/CS-HG81-10.html): `11-12-14-16-18-20-22-25-28-32T`

I think you would not notice the difference when riding. All the shimano 10s cassettes have the same sprocket spacing so from that perspective are fully interchangeable.

I believe that the SLX is a better quality part.

Answer (score 5):

With 10-speed, no problem to mix MTB and road cassettes. From 11-speed, road cassettes requires a 1.85mm longer freehub body (only the ones with the largest sprocket that is smaller than 34T though).